# Do I need "his" and "her" in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Perhaps Tom hadn’t meant **his** “We can meet at McDonald’s tomorrow.”
>   Even though Mary had meant **her** “Sure, I’ve been craving junk
>   food!”

Do I need the **his** and **her**. Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do, because it implies that the person(tom or Mary) is the one who 'owns' the sentence, or the one who said it.

Although it can be said like this, it isn't the best way to write. I would recommend changing at least one of them to something like 'Perhaps Tom hadn’t meant it when he said “We can meet at McDonald’s tomorrow.”' because it makes the sentence flow better. (my English teachers have told me to change sentences like this before)